# How can I retrive other values of form 1 when returning data from form2?

Tags: c#

Code of `form1`,

```
Picklist f2 = new Picklist(Query, this.Text);
f2.Show();
```

Code of `form2`,

```
DataGridViewRow Row = dgvPicklist.Rows[index];
this.Hide();
ItemMaster f2 = new ItemMaster(Row);
f2.Show();
```

Comment: you mean you want to send values from form1 to form2 when opening the form2?

Comment: no i have some fields in form1 . and which are not related to returning values from form 2 . so when i returns value from form2 in form1 only returned value showing other values got removed..... ItemMaster f2 = new ItemMaster(Row); only this rows values i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to send values from form1 to form2:

In form1:

```
form2 F = new form2(something);  // something is the value you need to send
F.show();
```

In form2:

```
public form2(string x)  //Considering the type of your value is string, you can replace that with the required data type.
{
    string something = x;  //sets the value of x to something. Just like it was in form1.
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

I have considered the datatype of the value you wanted to transfer as `string`.

You could change it as required.

Comment: i have some fields in form1 . and which are not related to returning values from form 2 . so when i returns value from form2 in form1 only returned value showing other values got removed..... ItemMaster f2 = new ItemMaster(Row); only this rows values i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ShowModal()` Instead of `Show()`:

```
 Picklist f2 = new Picklist(Query, this.Text);
 f2.ShowModal();
 string valueFromForm1 = TextBox1.Text;
```

`ShowModal()` waits till the opened form closes, and then executes the rest of the code

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Comment: I used this so its showing form1 in two different tabs in one tab i entered data n in second tab data which r sentback  from second form.. but i want all data in single tab .